# Salt Bridge for Microbial Fuel Cell: Full or Partly Full?

Tags: electricity, fuel

I'm making a microbial fuel cell out of benthic mud and salt water in containers. My salt bridge will be made of agar and table salt solidified in PVC pipes. Does the salt bridge connecting the anode (benthic mud) and cathode (salt water) have to be full of the agar-salt solution, or can it be partly full?

Comment: Partly full bridges can be partly functional with being partly durable. :-)

Comment: The solution (gel) in the bridge has to make electrical contact with mud and salt solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the salt bridge connecting the anode (benthic mud) and cathode
>   (salt water) have to be full of the agar-salt solution, or can it be
>   partly full

There should be no air gaps or cracks so that the circuit does not break anywhere. Take a narrow PVC pipe if your concern is using too much of agar-salt solution.